# problema con if dentro de foreach

Tags: php, mysql

estoy realizando una recorrido a un array  que guarde como `$Dat_productos_consult`  y  quiero que me realice la búsqueda  si se cumplen las condiciones que le estoy dando.

Por ejemplo si categoría es igual a `0` entonces  colócame en el `if` que tengo abajo la consulta que estoy haciendo, sino pues que siga bajando y así sucesivamente.

El problema es que `$Consult` no me lo coloca en el `if` de abajo, no se que estoy haciendo mal, soy nuevo en esto, pero creo que es algo de como lo escribo en `$Consult`, por que si coloco la consulta directa en el IF funcionan bien, pero si las guardo en la variable y luego se las pago ps no me hace la consulta bien.

```
    $Dat_productos_consult = $_SESSION['data_productos'];        


    foreach ($Dat_productos_consult as $item){

            if ($Idcat_pro==0) { 
            
                $Consult = "$item[$array_productos_idpais]==$Pais_emp and $item[$array_productos_iddepartamento]==$Iddepart and $item[$array_productos_idtipo_comercio]==$Idtip_comercio";
            

                }elseif (!empty($Idcat_pro) and $Idcat_pro!=0 and empty($Idsubcat_pro) or !empty($Idcat_pro) and $Idcat_pro!=0 and $Idsubcat_pro==0) { 

            
        
                $Consult = "$item[$array_productos_idpais]==$Pais_emp and $item[$array_productos_iddepartamento]==$Iddepart and $item[$array_productos_idtipo_comercio]==$Idtip_comercio and $item[$array_productos_idcategoria]==$Idcat_pro";
    

                }elseif (!empty($Idcat_pro) and $Idcat_pro!=0 and !empty($Idsubcat_pro) and $Idsubcat_pro!=0 and empty($Idsubcat_final) or !empty($Idcat_pro) and $Idcat_pro!=0 and !empty($Idsubcat_pro) and $Idsubcat_pro!=0 and $Idsubcat_final==0) { 
 
                $Consult = "$item[$array_productos_idpais]==$Pais_emp and $item[$array_productos_iddepartamento]==$Iddepart and $item[$array_productos_idtipo_comercio]==$Idtip_comercio and $item[$array_productos_idcategoria]==$Idcat_pro and $item[$array_productos_idsubcategoria]==$Idsubcat_pro";


                }elseif (!empty($Idcat_pro) and $Idcat_pro!=0 and !empty($Idsubcat_pro) and $Idsubcat_pro!=0 and $Idsubcat_final!=0 and empty($Idultimo_prod) or !empty($Idcat_pro) and $Idcat_pro!=0 and !empty($Idsubcat_pro) and $Idsubcat_pro!=0 and $Idsubcat_final!=0 and $Idultimo_prod==0) { 
 

                $Consult = "$item[$array_productos_idpais]==$Pais_emp and $item[$array_productos_iddepartamento]==$Iddepart and $item[$array_productos_idtipo_comercio]==$Idtip_comercio and $item[$array_productos_idcategoria]==$Idcat_pro and $item[$array_productos_idsubcategoria]==$Idsubcat_pro and $item[$array_productos_idsubcategoria_final]==$Idsubcat_final";
            
                

                }elseif (!empty($Idcat_pro) and $Idcat_pro!=0 and !empty($Idsubcat_pro) and $Idsubcat_pro!=0 and $Idsubcat_final!=0 and $Idultimo_prod!=0 or !empty($Idcat_pro) and $Idcat_pro!=0 and !empty($Idsubcat_pro) and $Idsubcat_pro!=0 and $Idsubcat_final!=0 and $Idultimo_prod!=0) { 

                $Consult = "$item[$array_productos_idpais]==$Pais_emp and $item[$array_productos_iddepartamento]==$Iddepart and $item[$array_productos_idtipo_comercio]==$Idtip_comercio and $item[$array_productos_idcategoria]==$Idcat_pro and $item[$array_productos_idsubcategoria]==$Idsubcat_pro and $item[$array_productos_idsubcategoria_final]==$Idsubcat_final and $item[$array_productos_idultima_categoria]==$Idultimo_prod";
        
                }
```

```
if ($Consult){
            
    echo $Consult;
}
```

resultado de vardump

```
     array(16) { [0]=> array(37) { ["id_pr"]=> int(110) ["id_em"]=> int(3953) ["id_per_ad_pre"]=> int(1) ["id_per_ad_apro"]=> int(0) ["est_pr"]=> int(3) ["idp"]=> int(13) ["idd"]=> int(178) ["idt_t_com"]=> int(7) ["id_ca"]=> int(38) ["id_s_c"]=> int(161) ["id_s_c_f"]=> int(150) ["id_u_c_u"]=> int(47) ["id_tiemp_em"]=> int(0) ["id_cond_p"]=> int(1) ["id_tip_p_serv"]=> int(0) ["est"]=> int(1) ["nac"]=> int(0) ["inte"]=> int(0) ["sta"]=> string(8) "standard" ["rev"]=> int(0) ["nom"]=> string(23) "Amgo en perfecto estado" ["carac"]=> string(12) "Celular amgo" ["dimen"]=> string(7) "40 x 40" ["cant"]=> int(20) ["pre"]=> string(6) "100.00" ["pre_pu"]=> string(4) "0.00" ["imgu"]=> string(59) "VZLA-CED-317434650_Pca5fuy676TdSJ1bruvh_20220830_102744.jpg" ["imgd"]=> string(0) "" ["imgt"]=> string(0) "" ["imgcu"]=> string(0) "" ["imgcin"]=> string(0) "" ["fech_r"]=> string(10) "2022-08-31" ["fech_ven"]=> NULL ["fech_h"]=> NULL ["fech_h_mod"]=> string(19) "2022-08-31 00:44:15" ["revis"]=> int(0) ["modifi"]=> NULL } [1]=> array(37) { ["id_pr"]=> int(108) ["id_em"]=> int(3953) ["id_per_ad_pre"]=> int(1) ["id_per_ad_apro"]=> int(0) ["est_pr"]=> int(3) ["idp"]=> int(13) ["idd"]=> int(178) ["idt_t_com"]=> int(7) ["id_ca"]=> int(38) ["id_s_c"]=> int(161) ["id_s_c_f"]=> int(150) ["id_u_c_u"]=> int(47) ["id_tiemp_em"]=> int(0) ["id_cond_p"]=> int(0) ["id_tip_p_serv"]=> int(0) ["est"]=> int(1) ["nac"]=> int(0) ["inte"]=> int(0) ["sta"]=> string(8) "standard" ["rev"]=> int(0) ["nom"]=> string(17) "Celular amgo aaee" ["carac"]=> string(28) "Producto en excelente estado" ["dimen"]=> string(5) "20x20" ["cant"]=> int(20) ["pre"]=> string(5) "20.00" ["pre_pu"]=> string(4) "0.00" ["imgu"]=> string(59) "VZLA-CED-317434650_tXkX7SfvW524PdOHHbSZ_20220829_221735.jpg" ["imgd"]=> string(59) "VZLA-CED-317434650_hZ40IwM0AhCHUDEASXRV_20220829_221745.jpg" ["imgt"]=> string(77) "VZLA-CED-317434650_23gFZGET9xIE68X9Kn9Z_Screenshot_20220829-162809_Chrome.jpg" ["imgcu"]=> string(0) "" ["imgcin"]=> string(0) "" ["fech_r"]=> string(10) "2022-08-30" ["fech_ven"]=> NULL ["fech_h"]=> NULL ["fech_h_mod"]=> string(19) "2022-08-30 17:33:55" ["revis"]=> int(0) ["modifi"]=> NULL } [2]=> array(37) { ["id_pr"]=> int(105) ["id_em"]=> int(3953) ["id_per_ad_pre"]=> int(1) ["id_per_ad_apro"]=> int(0) ["est_pr"]=> int(3) ["idp"]=> int(13) ["idd"]=> int(178) ["idt_t_com"]=> int(7) ["id_ca"]=> int(38) ["id_s_c"]=> int(161) ["id_s_c_f"]=> int(150) ["id_u_c_u"]=> int(47) ["id_tiemp_em"]=> int(0) ["id_cond_p"]=> int(0) ["id_tip_p_serv"]=> int(0) ["est"]=> int(1) ["nac"]=> int(0) ["inte"]=> int(0) ["sta"]=> string(8) "standard" ["rev"]=> int(0) ["nom"]=> string(12) "Celular amgo" ["carac"]=> string(28) "Producto en excelente estado" ["dimen"]=> string(5) "20x20" ["cant"]=> int(20) ["pre"]=> string(5) "20.00" ["pre_pu"]=> string(4) "0.00" ["imgu"]=> string(59) "VZLA-CED-317434650_5Yq0zTKTnb3Saf1bPT67_20220829_221735.jpg" ["imgd"]=> string(59) "VZLA-CED-317434650_9bSpuDqSGrqa768itqpI_20220829_221745.jpg" ["imgt"]=> string(77) "VZLA-CED-317434650_aH6m6HakXgBvRwhMceST_Screenshot_20220829-162809_Chrome.jpg" ["imgcu"]=> string(0) "" ["imgcin"]=> string(0) "" ["fech_r"]=> string(10) "2022-08-30" ["fech_ven"]=> NULL ["fech_h"]=> NULL ["fech_h_mod"]=> string(19) "2022-08-30 16:34:05" ["revis"]=> int(0) ["modifi"]=> NULL } [3]=> array(37) { ["id_pr"]=> int(102) ["id_em"]=> int(3943) ["id_per_ad_pre"]=> int(1) ["id_per_ad_apro"]=> int(0) ["est_pr"]=> int(3) ["idp"]=> int(13) ["idd"]=> int(178) ["idt_t_com"]=> int(2) ["id_ca"]=> int(92) ["id_s_c"]=> int(420) ["id_s_c_f"]=> int(0) ["id_u_c_u"]=> int(0) ["id_tiemp_em"]=> int(0) ["id_cond_p"]=> int(1) ["id_tip_p_serv"]=> int(1) ["est"]=> int(1) ["nac"]=> int(0) ["inte"]=> int(0) ["sta"]=> string(8) "standard" ["rev"]=> int(0) ["nom"]=> string(11) "nuevo nuevo" ["carac"]=> string(9) "excelente" ["dimen"]=> NULL ["cant"]=> int(0) ["pre"]=> string(4) "0.00" ["pre_pu"]=> string(5) "11.60" ["imgu"]=> string(63) "VZLA-CED-317434650_YvNXiO2PyL4uBBw8lMPa_IMG-20220422-WA0096.jpg" ["imgd"]=> string(79)
```

Colocando la consulta directa dentro del if si sale todo bien, asi como la paso por aca abajo

```
$Dat_productos_consult = $_SESSION['data_productos'];   



foreach ($Dat_productos_consult as $item){


            if (!empty($Idcat_pro) and $Idcat_pro!=0 and !empty($Idsubcat_pro) and $Idsubcat_pro!=0 and $Idsubcat_final!=0 and empty($Idultimo_prod) or !empty($Idcat_pro) and $Idcat_pro!=0 and !empty($Idsubcat_pro) and $Idsubcat_pro!=0 and $Idsubcat_final!=0 and $Idultimo_prod==0) { 


                if($item[$array_productos_idpais]==$Pais_emp and $item[$array_productos_iddepartamento]==$Iddepart and $item[$array_productos_idtipo_comercio]==$Idtip_comercio and $item[$array_productos_idcategoria]==$Idcat_pro and $item[$array_productos_idsubcategoria]==$Idsubcat_pro and $item[$array_productos_idsubcategoria_final]==$Idsubcat_final){
            




                    $Idproductos = $item[$array_productos_idproductos];         
                    $estatus_product = $item[$array_productos_estatus_producto];        
                    $Idtiempo_ent = $item[$array_productos_idtiempo_entrega];               
                    $Estadal = $item[$array_productos_estatal];                          
                    $Nacional = $item[$array_productos_nacional];   
                    $Internacional = $item[$array_productos_internacional];
                    $Standard = $item[$array_productos_standard];   
                    $Revendedores = $item[$array_productos_revendedores];
                    $Nombre_product = $item[$array_productos_nombre];       
                    $Caracteristicas = $item[$array_productos_caracteristicas]; 
                    $Dimensiones = $item[$array_productos_dimensiones];
                    $Cantidad = $item[$array_productos_cantidad];   
                    $Precio = $item[$array_productos_precio];   
                    $img_uno = $item[$array_productos_img_uno]; 
                    $img_dos = $item[$array_productos_img_dos]; 
                    $img_tres = $item[$array_productos_img_tres];   
                    $img_cuatro = $item[$array_productos_img_cuatro];
                    $img_cinco = $item[$array_productos_img_cinco];
                    $fecha_reg = $item[$array_productos_fecha_reg];
                    $Revision = $item[$array_productos_revision];
                    $Modificacion = $item[$array_productos_modificacion];
                            
                    
                    
                        $repetidos[0] = ""; 
                        foreach ($Dat_tiempo_entrega_productos_consult as $item){
                            if($item[$array_tiempo_entrega_idtiempo_entrega]==$Idtiempo_ent){
                    
                                $repetidos[0] = $item[$array_tiempo_entrega_tiempo_entrega];    
                                $Tiempo_entrega = $item[$array_tiempo_entrega_tiempo_entrega];  
                            }
                                        
                        }
                    
                        if(!empty($repetidos[0])){  
                    
                    
                        }else{
                    
                            $Tiempo_entrega = "Entrega Inmediata";
                    
                        }
                            unset($repetidos);           
                     
                    foreach ($Dat_estado_productos_consult as $item){
                        if($item[$array_estatus_producto_idestatus_producto]==$estatus_product){
                            $Estatus_actual = strtoupper($item[$array_estatus_producto_estatus_producto]);
                    }   
                    }       

                            
                    ?>
                    
                                                
                    
                    <br>
                    
                    <div id="<? echo $Idproductos."_content"; ?>" class="stilo_nav">
                    
                                    <div align="left"  style="width: 7rem;">
                                        <img class="card-img-top" src="productos_clientes/<? echo $img_uno; ?>">
                                        </div>
                                
                        <br>
                    Estatus:<strong> <span class="promo_red_peque"><? echo $Estatus_actual;  ?></span></strong>  <br>
                    Producto:<strong>  <? echo $Nombre_product;  ?></strong> <br>   
                    Identificador del producto:<strong>  <? echo $Idproductos;  ?></strong>  <br>
                    Cantidad:<strong>  <? echo $Cantidad;  ?></strong><br>
                    Caracteristicas:<strong>  <? echo $Caracteristicas;  ?></strong><br> 
                    Precio:<strong>  <? echo number_format($Precio, 2, ",", ".")." ".$Moneda_deb;  ?></strong><br><br>
                        
                        
                    <?  
                    
                            if ($Revision==1){
                                
                            ?>
                        
                        <br>
                    <strong><span class="promo_red">  <? echo $Modificacion;  ?></strong></strong><br><br><br>  
                        
                            <?  
                            }
                        
                    ?>  
                        

                                <article class="user-panel-product-edit main">
                            
                            
                           <form name="<? echo $Idproductos; ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="buscar_product_nombre.php"  method="POST">
                               
                        <input type="hidden" name="nombre_producto" id="nombre_producto" value="<? echo $Idproductos; ?>" />    
                               
                                          <div class="wrap_button">
                      <button type="button" class="button_submit click_edit_product" name="<? echo $Idproductos; ?>">Editar</button>
                    </div>         
                            
                          <br><br>     
                        
                               
                                   
                        </form>
                        
                        
                        </article>
                               


                        <article class="user-panel-product-activar main">
                            
                            
                           <form name="<? echo $Idproductos; ?>"  enctype="multipart/form-data" action="inactivar_product.php"  method="POST">
                               
                        <input type="hidden" name="idproducto" id="idproducto" value="<? echo $Idproductos; ?>" />  
                        <input type="hidden" name="status_pro" id="status_pro" value="<? echo $estatus_product; ?>" />         
                        
                               
                        <?
                        
                            if ($estatus_product==1){
                                
                            ?>
                    
                                      <div class="wrap_button">
                      <button type="button" class="button_submit click_act_product" name="<? echo $Idproductos; ?>">Inactivar</button>
                    </div>         
                               
                          <br><br>     
                            
                        
                               <?
                                
                                
                            }
                            
                            if ($estatus_product==2){
                                
                                
                            ?>   
                                      <div class="wrap_button">
                      <button type="button" class="button_submit click_act_product" name="<? echo $Idproductos; ?>">Activar</button>
                    </div>                                        
                                
                               
                               
                          <br><br>     
                            
                        
                               <?           
                                
                                
                            }
                            
                            
                            ?>
                               
                          
                        
                        </form>
                        
                        
                        </article>
                        
                        
                        <article class="user-panel-product-elim main">
                        
                     <form name="<? echo $Idproductos;  ?>" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="eliminar_product.php"  method="POST"> 
                        
                        <input type="hidden" name="idproducto" id="idproducto" value="<? echo $Idproductos; ?>" />   
                         
                    
                    
                              <div class="wrap_button">
                      <button type="button" class="button_submit click_elim_product" name="<? echo $Idproductos; ?>">Eliminar producto</button>
                    </div>                                        
                                          
                            
                         
                          <br><br>     
                            
                        
                         
                            </form> 
                            
                             </article>
                        
                        <br><br><br>
                         <div id="<? echo $Idproductos; ?>"></div>
                        
                         <br><br>
                    </div>
                    
                    
                      
                    
                    
                    
                    
                    <?      
                        }
        
            





        



}
             
}
```

Comment: Podrías colocar un ejemplo de que sale cuando ejecutas `var_dump($Dat_productos_consult); die();` antes del `foreach`?

Comment: como que tu segundo codigo no se deja ver muy bien ... te hechare una mano.

Comment: listo ya le coloque el resultado del vardump, pero los resultados estan bien, el problema es la consulta que estoy haciendo en el if, o sea quiero colocar los  los datos que quiero consultar en la variable $Consult y luego usarlos en el if dependiendo la condición, pero nada que me hace el if como tiene que ser colocando la variable $Consult dentro de el, pero si coloco la consulta directa en el if ps asi si la hace sin problema

Comment: quieres que consult sea parte de tu consulta a la base de datos, osea el query???

Comment: usa `if(!empty($Consult)){...` con esto validas que `$Consult` no este vacio

Comment: ok lo acabo de hacer como me dijiste, pero fíjate que estoy colocando un echo $Consult  despues del if(!empty($Consult)){...    y de resultado el echo me esta dando lo siguiente

13==13 and 178==178 and 7==7 and 38==38 and 161==160   luego esta

13==13 and 178==178 and 2==7 and 92==38 and 420==160  y asi sucesivamente, entonces a lo que me refiero es que si te fijas con esta haciendo la consulta, por que los valores del final no son iguales y incluso asi esta mostrándome todos los resultados y no los que quiero que es cuando se cumpla la condición

Comment: No será que la variable $consult la estas pisando? porque está dentro de un for, o sea por cada item la reescribes.

Comment: fijate que acabo de hacer una edicion para que veas el ejemplo donde coloco la consulta directa y asi efectivamente me hace todo sin problemas, intentare ver si para lo que e dices, que sea q por estar dentro del for la este afectando en algo